# Does use of LanguagePrimitives.xxxWithMeasure functions affect runtime performance?

Tags: performance, f#, annotations, units-of-measurement

Does use of LanguagePrimitives.xxxWithMeasure functions affect runtime performance?

Is there any other way to annotate external functions (not implemented in F#)?

I have seen this in MSDN: "Units of measure are used for compile-time unit checking but are not persisted in the run-time environment. Therefore, they do not affect performance." but want to make sure that it covers absolutely every scenario and there is no runtime footprint whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to check is to look at the compiled code with a decompiler such as ILSpy. The following:

```
[<Measure>] type M

let test(x: int) =
    let y = LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure<M> x
    (x, y)
```

compiled and passed to ILSpy, decompiles to:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> test(int x)
{
    return new Tuple<int, int>(x, x);
}
```

So it doesn't have any runtime cost.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you care?  If you've got specific performance goals, then test against them.  It would be trivial for you to write code to test whether there's a performance penalty that's meaningful to you.

Having said that, you can find [where these functions are implemented](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs) in the F# standard library's source and see that there should be no runtime impact.

Comment: That's true, but regardless of the source of the answer it would be nice for the next person asking to be able to just google it. I certainly appreciated MSDN info about performance effect of using them in a straightforward way and not having to test that.

Comment: If F# is doing some compiler "magic" to get rid of measurement code when used in a straightforward way, it is entirely possible that it is doing some magic with xxxWithMeasure functions. The only way to tell would be testing as you suggested, but it still would require posting a question and answer here on SO to share the information.